# How to prompt for user info for a key in a map type variable in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I have the following variable in terraform:

```
rds_config_list = [
  {
    rds_name                           = "shiftleft"
    rds_identifier                     = "shiftleft-postgres"
    rds_password                       = <USETINPUT>
    rds_snapshot_identifier            = "shiftleft"
    rds_postgres_instance_class        = "db.m6g.large"
    rds_postgres_engine_version        = "13.3"
    rds_postgres_family                = "postgres13"
    rds_postgres_allocated_storage     = 100
    rds_postgres_max_allocated_storage = 1000
    rds_backup_retention_period        = 7
    rds_postgres_multi_az              = false
    rds_postgres_deletion_protection   = false
  },
  {
    rds_name                           = "shiftleft2"
    rds_identifier                     = "shiftleft2-postgres"
    rds_password                       = <USETINPUT>
    rds_snapshot_identifier            = "shiftleft2"
    rds_postgres_instance_class        = "db.m6g.large"
    rds_postgres_engine_version        = "13.3"
    rds_postgres_family                = "postgres13"
    rds_postgres_allocated_storage     = 100
    rds_postgres_max_allocated_storage = 1000
    rds_backup_retention_period        = 7
    rds_postgres_multi_az              = false
    rds_postgres_deletion_protection   = false
  }
]
```

i want to prompt for user input for the passwords for each of them and not have the same password for all databases, this is inside a .tfvars file. is there any way to do it?

Comment: Even if it was, its a bad security practice. All these passwords will end up in **plain text** in your state file, for everyone to see who has access to it.

Comment: @Marcin the state file is encrypted on a remote s3 bucket. it's better then having it plaintext in the code source, at least for now..

Comment: In that case create the two password variables `var "pass1" {}` and `var "pass2" {}`.

Comment: @Marcin that's what I'm trying to avoid, i wanted it to be dynamic and not adding more variables just more items to the map list. i think it's not supported though :( maybe need to reconsider password management in terraform entirely..

Comment: There is no other way sadly, unless you are going to implement some wrapper around TF which is going to query for these passwords.